# Meta keywords ainda é necessário?

Tags: html-meta-tag

Estive lendo sobre as meta tags, e muitos sites que já não é mais importante para o Google e outros buscadores o uso da meta 'keywords', causando certa dúvida de uso no projeto em que estou desenvolvendo.

Afinal, meta keywords ainda é necessário? Ainda tem algum peso para os buscadores?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O Google não utiliza a meta tag keywords para processar o ranking dos sites que serão exibidos em uma busca. No link abaixo você pode verificar quais meta tags o robô do google utiliza para indexar os sites.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=pt-BR

O buscador Yahoo utiliza essa meta tag, porém as palavras contidas nela possuem menor relevância do que as palavras de outros lugares, como por exemplo as contidas dentro das tags body, title, description ou anchor.

O Bing utiliza a mesma ideia do Yahoo: as meta tags são um sinal, porém com muito pouca relevância.

Se você estiver com os buscadores em mente, utilizar a meta tag keyword não vai ajudar. Está tag já virou história :)

Comment: Observando por esse ponto de vista, alem das tags description, title, H's, quais seriam as melhores formas para o SEO?

Comment: Em relação aos buscadores essas são as mais importantes! Com certeza a tag title é a mais importante de todas! Se o título for bem escolhido fará bastante diferença na indexação.

Answer (score 1):

Se vc ver bem não existi tanta necessidade mesmo das keyword , as palavras chaves também estão sendo adicionadas nas [descrições em negrito](https://skate-eletrico-hoverboard.lojaintegrada.com.br/) moderadamente para dar relevância ao conteúdo. é muito bom também adicionar aquelas palavras chaves compostas q o Google sugere, ao buscar por uma palavra chave no navegador, o Google sugere sinônimos compostos mais buscados q é bom adicionar ao conteudo (descrições).